# dplyr, ODBC, SAS, and escaped table names

Tags: r, sas, odbc, dplyr

I've been trying, with some success, to use the development version of dplyr to access a SAS table via ODBC on Windows.

When I send a bare SQL statement, I can access a table:

```
a <- tbl(dplyr_src, sql('SELECT * FROM MAPS.Bhutan'))
```

When I try to access lazily load a table, however, I run into a problem with SAS table naming conventions in SQL.

```
b <- tbl(dplyr_src, 'Maps.Bhutan') # fails
```

From what documentation I can find, SAS will not accept quoted table names in queries.

```
When XXX in "ODBCAPPL"(0) called prepare for SELECT * FROM
"Maps.Bhutan" AS "zzz30" WHERE (0 = 1) from SQLVIEW:
ERROR: SQL passthru expression contained these errors: 
ERROR: The value 'MAPS.BHUTAN'n is not a valid SAS name..
```

Short of defining a new src for this ODBC connection to SAS, is there any way to tell dplyr not to quote table names? Alternatively, is there a startup command for SAS that will convince it allow quoted identifiers?

Comment: Did you try using `maps.'bhutan'n` as the name? Perhaps then since the value already includes quotes it won't add extra double quotes before sending it to SAS?